# Upload a URL as a file using PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

I have images that are hosted on a CDN, and I want to upload that image to some other system via their API. Normally I would just use curl and put an @ character in front of the file to upload. Since this is a URL, that won't work since it expects the file to be local. I don't want to copy it local first since the files could be videos and that could be time consuming.

It seems there should be a way to do this with PHP curl. I'm open to using sockets instead, but I'm not sure how to simulate how curl does the submission.

Comment: so you want to download the file from the CDN to that "other system", right?

Comment: yes. Ideally the other system would download it directly, but that is not an option.

Comment: And can't you have on that other system a PHP file that receives a download URL as parameter and when called it proceeds to download the file? This way all you would need to do would be to "ping" that script and it will start the download from the CDN using the URL you provide.

Comment: No, it's not my system. It's someone else's API I'm trying to integrate with. That would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$save_file_url =  file_get_contents($your_files_CDN_file_URL);

$fp = fopen('test','w');
fwrite($fp,$save_file_url);
$save_file = realpath('test') ;

$url = "http://URL_TO_SEND_FILE/get_file.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$post = array(
    "file_is_this"=> "@".$save_file,
    "app"=>'test'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

And you will recieve file at get_file.php.

Comment: realpath doesn't work on urls, it just returns false (failure). A CDN is something like Akamai.

Comment: oh yes, try $save_file = file_get_contents($your_files_at_CDN_file_URL)

Comment: that creates a form field with binary data, not a file attachment that would appear in the $_FILES array

Comment: That's copying the file locally. I know that will work. That is what I am trying to avoid doing.

Comment: oh, while editing forgot your this requirement. What about [scp WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy), [one more link](http://www.unixmantra.com/2013/04/scp-command-examples-linux-unix-tutorial.html#.UxBfQeOSwZM) I haven't used it.